# Jquery/javascript fade in each element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, fadein

By default image and text will fade in one after another once there are loaded, but is there a way to have a fading effect added on "each" element once there are loaded?

I can load the element using the code below:

```
$("#element,#element2,#element3,#element4").fadeIn("slow");
```

but the downsides are:

1. I have to specify all the elements in the page, #div1,#div3,#container2.....
2. Also the elements can only fade in once the page finish loading all together,but what I want is fade in the elements before all the html finishes loaded.

Is it possible?

Comment: do you know class? if not, i think it will solve ur problem. I noticed you only use ids'

Answer (score 1):

I would give each element a specific class, then reference it with $(".whatever"). You also will probably check out $.each(), which iterates through objects. To fade in as the page loads, you would need to place the code, or call the function outside the document ready(), somewhere near the beginning of the html.

Answer (score 0):

you should use **class** attribute for the elements. You can access and control all the elements which have a particular class, you need not specify the **id** of each and every element. Here is a **demo [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/QXxQ4/1/)** for you :

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="btn_fade_out" value="Fade Out">
<input type="button" id="btn_fade_in" value="Fade In">
<br>    
<div class="my_class">Element 1</div>
<div class="my_class">Element 2</div>
<div class="my_class">Element 3</div>
    <img src="abc.png" height="50px" width="50px" border="1" class="my_class"></img>
```

JS:

```
$('#btn_fade_out').click(function(){
    $('.my_class').fadeOut(1000);
});

$('#btn_fade_in').click(function(){
    $('.my_class').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be having a class in common for all the elements you want to fade on load
and then use

```
$('.class').fadeIn(1000);

$('.class').fadeOut(1000);
```